# Was Star Trek's "Shore Leave" explicitly inspired by Disneyland?

Tags: star-trek, history-of

[Shore Leave](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shore_Leave_(episode)) was broadcast in 1966, about 11 years after Disneyland opened in California.  Is there any documentation mentioning a connection between the immersive resort with [robotic devices simulating real and fictional people and animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio-Animatronics) and the episode's similar concept?

Comment: If it was Disneyland the crew wouldn't be allowed to just wander around by themselves on an empty planet, there'd be a whole staff of aliens dedicated to making sure the visit went exactly according to parameters and making sure the crew didn't go anywhere they weren't supposed to. (A bit like "Justice", come to think of it, except I don't think people are generally sentenced to death at Disneyland...)

Comment: Yes, but ***if the Pirates of the Caribbean breaks down, the pirates don't eat tourists***

Comment: I find it doubtful that Disneyland was anything but a small part of the inspiration. The theme of the episode, according to Sturgeon, is the need for fantasy in relaxation, and this need for fantasy or imagination was a central part of Sturgeon's writing long before *Shore Leave*.

Comment: Thank you -  with a cite of Sturgeon's stated inspiration this would be a good answer.

Comment: @Cadence It's worse, they lock you in the "Small World" ride.

Comment: That's prohibited by the Organian treaty after that unfortunate incident with Ayelborne and the lederhosen

Comment: Armus might have loved that planet! Though who knows if the sensors could read its thoughts.